# DataFrame to JSON format without column names

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a dataset in the following format below

```
Parameter    Value    Col3
A              1.0     2.0
B              1.0     2.5
dx             0.2     1.0
```

and I use a python script to save the output in json format given below

```
#foo.py

import pandas
import json
#..

df.to_json('foo.json'), orient='records', lines = True, indent=1)`
```

Output:

```
{
  "Parameter":"A",
  "Value":1.0,
  "Col3":2.0, 
 }

 {
  "Parameter":"B",
  "Value":1.0,
  "Col3" : 2.5,
 }

 {
  "Parameter":"dx",
  "Value":0.2,
  "Col3" : 2.5,
 }
```

I would prefer the json format to be like

```
{
        "A"    : [1.0, 2.0]  
        "B"    : [1.0, 2.5]
        "dx"    :[0.2, 1.0]
}
```

Can someone suggest how to get the desired output format? Considering I have varying column name and number of columns across various datasets.

Answer (score 2):

Create `Series` first:

```
df.set_index('Parameter')['Value'].to_json('foo.json', indent=1)

{
 "A":1.0,
 "B":1.0,
 "dx":0.2
}
```

EDIT: If need processing multiple columns:

```
df.set_index('Parameter').agg(list, axis=1).to_json('foo.json', indent=1)
```

If need set first column by position:

```
df.set_index(df.columns[0]).agg(list, axis=1).to_json('foo.json', indent=1)
```

Comment: thanks, but what if my no of columns and their names varies?

Comment: @newstudent - what is `print (df.info())` ?

Comment: @newstudent - Or `print (df.columns)` ?

Comment: for print(df.columns) `Index(['Parameter', 'Value'], dtype='object')`

Comment: @newstudent - Yes, so it means columns names are `Parameter` and `Value`, so solution working well.

Comment: it is, but I have several datasets with different column names, and I dont wnat to change it here `df.set_index('Parameter')['Value']`

Comment: @newstudent -there are always 2 columns?

Comment: no, even no. of columns change.

Comment: @newstudent - So need processing first 2 columns?

Comment: no, It can be any column in the dataset. may be 3 or 4 columns too

Comment: @newstudent - Can you give example of `3 columns DataFrame` with expected ouput? Because ouput is different like in question for 2 columns

Comment: @jezael I have modifed my question

Comment: @newstudent - Can you check edited answer?